# The pink comb tantalizes me! How can I get one?

Tags: castle-crashers

For those of you who have played **Castle Crashers**, you will know that at the end of the "Medusa's Lair" stage, the boss (Medusa) drops a pink comb into the background before the conflict.  I'm not entirely sure of this, but it *looks* like I should be able to get my hands on it somehow, and probably use it as a weapon in the game.  I would love dearly to hit stuff with that comb.

But alas, all of my efforts to obtain the Medusa's comb have proved fruitless.  So far as I can tell, none of the Animal Orbs (Pets) will get it for me.  I came up empty handed with **every** animal orb, including the Cardinal, Hawkster, and Owlet orbs.  Copious amounts of Google-fu only turned up vague rumours that the comb is not in fact an attainable object, although it *feels* like one.

Can someone confirm this, and tell me whether or not I am wasting my time trying to get the comb?

Comment: Sometimes a red herring is neither red nor a herring.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[This link](http://castlecrashers.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons) has a list of every weapon attainable in the game and how to unlock them all. *It does not have the comb as a usable weapon*.

I have every animal orb in my game and I know you don't get a comb from those.

However you can unlock one weapon in Medusa's lair. [The Buster Sword.](http://castlecrashers.wikia.com/wiki/Hole_Sword)

Comment: Yep, also known as the _Play-doh Pasta Maker_.  Thanks for the info!